# Gpg Keys not imported, cannot verify repomd.xml for repo

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I have updated CentOS kernel and restarted the local repo server. After that when I run `yum update` on client, I am getting `http://test.local/repos/test-extras/CentOS/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Gpg Keys not imported, cannot verify repomd.xml for repo test-extras`

I am not familer with yum repo server and looking for help to fix this issue. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.